# SQL Number Rows without ROW_NUMBER() with Partition By ? MariaDB 10.1

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.1

I would like to do this :

```
SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY score DESC, creationDate DESC) as num
FROM DB
ORDER BY score DESC, creationDate DESC
```

but in MariaDB 10.1, so row_number is not available. I managed to do this :

```
SELECT *, (@num:= @num + 1) AS num
from DB,
(SELECT @num:= 0 AS num1) AS c
order by score DESC, creationDate DESC
```

But I don't see how to put the partition by, so I could start a new count for any Id
(the final aim is to order by the num created)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can express this as:

```
SELECT db.*,
       (@rn := IF(@id = id, @rn + 1,
                  IF(@id := id, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as num
from (SELECT db.*
      FROM DB
      ORDER BY id, score DESC, creationDate DESC
     ) db CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0, @id := '') params;
```

Note:  This uses a subquery to order the rows *before* doing the calculation.  This was needed in the more recent pre-8.0 versions of MySQL.  I don't know if it is really needed in MariaDB.

Comment: Hi @Gordon, I have an issue. I double checked the results and it seems like for some reason, it works partially. In fact I got like : 3 times Id = 10 and num = 1. While I'd like to have a single value per Id. ex Id = 10, score =10, num = 1  ;   Id = 10, score =8, num = 2 ;  Id = 10, score =5, num = 3 ... And beginning again on new Id value

Comment: @Elcalli . . . Can you set up a db<>fiddle illustrating the issue?  In addition, a "single value per id" is not what `row_number()` does.  Perhaps you should be asking a *new* question.